# Travel in the US on J-1 Visa and ESTA

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, j1-visas, danish-citizens

Regarding travelling in and out of the US. I am on a J-1 visa and wish to go to The Bahamas in my grace period.

If I want to return to the US after The Bahamas I know that I cannot enter on my visa but can I enter on an ESTA instead?

Comment: Hi and welcome. What's your citizenship?

Comment: I a Danish citizen